# How to execute cron jobs automatically every week in magento 2 custom module?

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron

I have created crontab.xml in vendor/module/etc directory

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="get_carriers" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\GetCarriers" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

And create GetCarriers.php in Vendor/Module/Cron/GetCarriers.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;
     class GetCarriers {

     protected $_logger;

     public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
           $this->_logger = $logger;
     }

     public function execute() {
           $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
           $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
           $logger->addWriter($writer);
           $logger->info(__METHOD__);

           return $this;
     }
}
```

Now if i execute **php bin/magento cron:run --group="default"** cron run but i want it to execute automatically every week.

Comment: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/running-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/

Comment: already followed this not able to execute cron automatically

Answer (score 2):

Just change your crontab schedule as below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
       <job name="get_carriers" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\GetCarriers" method="execute">
           <schedule>0 0 * * 0</schedule>
       </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Above schedule run the cron job for every Sunday at 00:00:00

```
0 0 * * 0 == Sunday 00:00:00
.
.
.
.
.
0 0 * * 6 == Saturday 00:00:00
```

Simmilarly you can adjust time, you can use the online cron [formatter](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_0)  to adjust the settings and tested it immediately.

Note: I hope you already configure crontab, if not just run the below command to configure.

> php bin/magento cron:install

Comment: what should i do for testing purpose

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: appreciating but i want to test it on localhost right now cron job is only executing if command run not automatically

Comment: We can configure the cron schedule as much as near the current time e.g) 5 mins after and tested it

Comment: make sure cron service run on your system by runing the command `sudo service cron status`

Comment: cron_schedule table from database shows status as missed . what is wrong at my side what i am missing ?

Comment: `Store -> Configuration -> System -> Cron Configuration Option for group: default -> Missed if Not Run Within` increase this time and tested it.